# How to translate xml configuration bean to Java config bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am rewriting a legacy project using Quartz and Spring Framework. The original configuration is in XML and now I am translating it into Java Config. The xml configuration uses jobDetail to set the job detail property of the trigger bean. However, when I try to use the equivalent method, i.e. the setter: setJobDetails(simpleJobDetail), I got a warning that the setter does not have correct type (expecting JobDetails, but got MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean).

May I know whether it is correct to translate xml bean configuration to Java COnfig by using the equivalent named setter in Java COnfig?
Why in the XML property setting, the trigger bean can set its jobDetail property as the simpleJobDetail bean (which has type MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean) , while the Java Config could not?

XML config:

```
<!-- For times when you just need to invoke a method on a specific object -->
<bean id="simpleJobDetail"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="reader" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="readData" />
</bean>

<!-- Run the job every 60 seconds with initial delay of 1 second -->
 <bean id="trigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="600000" />
</bean>
```

Java Config:

```
    @Bean
public MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean simpleJobDetail() {
    MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean simpleJobDetail = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
    simpleJobDetail.setTargetObject(reader());
    simpleJobDetail.setTargetMethod("readData");
    return simpleJobDetail;
}



@Bean
private Object reader() {
    // TODO: 10/13/2016
    return null;
}

@Bean
public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean trigger() {
    final SimpleTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
    trigger.setJobDetail( simpleJobDetail()); // got warning about wrong type
    trigger.setRepeatInterval(60000);
    return trigger;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that simpleJobDetail() returns a factory, not the bean itself. You can rely on autowiring to inject a JobDetail built using this factory.

```
@Bean
public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean trigger(final JobDetail simpleJobDetail) {
    final SimpleTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
    trigger.setJobDetail(simpleJobDetail); // got warning about wrong type
    trigger.setRepeatInterval(60000);
    return trigger;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This behavior of factory bean is very interesting. Is there any systemic tutorial for factory beans? I googled a bit but can only find some bits and bites.

Comment: Nothing more than the official documentation:<br/>  [Customizing instantiation logic with a FactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) <br/>[Basic concepts: @Bean and @Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts) <br/>[What's a FactoryBean?](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean)